# Vuejs 2 with Vuetify draggable issue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, draggable, v-data-table

I have an existing v-data-table with the possible to select items and also expand it, to get more information.
Now I want to implement the draggable library, that I can sort the list by drag and drop.
But when I implement this library I lose the possible to expand a row.

v-data-table

```
<v-data-table
  dense
  v-model="selectedItems"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  class="mt-4"
  :single-select="editorModeLogic"
  item-key="id"
  show-select
  :loading="isLoading"
  loading-text="loading"
  show-expand
  :single-expand="true"
  :expanded.sync="expandedItems"
  @click:row="(item, slot) => slot.select(!slot.isSelected)"
  @item-selected="onItemRowSelected"
  :hide-default-footer="false"
  :items-per-page="-1"
>
  <template #body="props">
    <draggable :list="props.items" tag="tbody" :disabled="false" :move="onMoveCallback" @end="onDropCallback">
      <data-table-row-handler
        v-for="(item, index) in props.items"
        :key="index"
        :item="item"
        :showExpanded="true"
        :headers="headers"
        :selectedItems="selectedItems"
        :expandedItems="expandedItems"
        @checkbox-clicked="onCheckboxClicked"
        @expand-clicked="onExpandClicked"
      >
        <template v-slot:item.type="{ item }">
          <v-icon :color="item.type == 'search' ? 'primary' : 'amber accent-3'">{{ item.type == "search" ? "mdi-search" : "mdi-motion" }}</v-icon>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:item.status="{ item }">
          <v-icon :color="item.status == 'inactive' ? 'pink accent-3' : 'green accent-3'">{{
            item.status == "inactive" ? "mdi-cancel" : "mdi-check"
          }}</v-icon>
        </template>
      </data-table-row-handler>
    </draggable>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

DataTableRowHandler

```
<template>
  <tr :class="getClass">
    <td v-if="showExpanded">
      <v-icon @click.stop="onExpandClicked">
        {{ isExpanded ? "mdi-chevron-up" : "mdi-chevron-down" }}
      </v-icon>
    </td>
    <td>
      <v-checkbox :input-value="selectedItems.includes(item)" hide-details @click.stop @click="onClick"></v-checkbox>
    </td>
    <td v-for="(header, index) in headers" :key="index">
      <slot :item="item" :name="columnName(header)">
        <div>
          {{ getNonSlotValue(item, header) }}
        </div>
      </slot>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

and if i try to add the expanded slot like this

```
<template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
   <td :colspan="headers.length">
   </td>
</template>
```

nothing happens..

and if I create a second table without draggable and bind it to the same properties, the rows expand, if I click it on the first table, so the properties will be set correctly.